# LibGDX ImageButton resizeing

Tags: libgdx

How can I resize ImageButton ? It show very big on screen . How I know it is an Actor and it is not resizing automatically . I can`t find the method for resizing it. Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at this UI test: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/UITest.java

Comment: shall I use stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true); ?

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry.

Comment: If I knew, I would post a proper answer :) take a look at the sample (test) I linked, it should hopefully work well for you, and you can post your solution when you figure it out. I didn't see any obvious way to resize the button either and I don't use `Actor2d.ui`.

Comment: and what are you using for buttons that contain only image?

Comment: I'm using a combination of a sprite and an input "thing." (You can use an `InputProcessor` to track clicks.) It's an entity-component system which I added on top of libGDX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your ImageButton in a table. Set the size of it.  Add the table as an actor in your stage.

Here is an example:

```
ImageButton. ImageButton Style btnStyle new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle ();
btnStyle.up = skin.getDrawable ("your image");

btnB = new ImageButton (btnStyle);

stage.addActor ( table );

table.add (btnB).size (150, 200);
```